# Compute the splitting field and the Galois group of $x^4 - 5$ over $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{5})$.

Tags: galois-theory

I believe the splitting field is easily found by the following.

$x^4 - 5 = (x^2 - \sqrt{5})(x^2 + \sqrt{5})$, so the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5},i)$, or is this incorrect?

Once I obtain this, how to do I find the Galois group of this polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$?

Thanks!

Comment: Basically you are adjoining two square roots to $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$. As you get a quartic extension of $K$, the square roots are "unrelated". So for the purposes of finding the Galois group the situation is analogous to finding the Galois group of, say, $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)/\Bbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been a while since I've done Galois theory, but here's a shot at it.

I agree with your identification of the splitting field. To find the Galois group over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 5)$, it suffices to find the Galois group over $\mathbb Q$ and use the Galois correspondence. So, for fun, let's work out the entire Galois group over $\mathbb Q$.

The splitting field is over order $8$. We have the automorphisms
$$\alpha: \sqrt[4] 5 \rightarrow  i\sqrt[4] 5,$$
$$\beta: i\rightarrow -i,$$
and together these generate a a group of order 8, so they generate the entire Galois group. It remains to work out what group of order 8 this is. There are [5 groups of order 8](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_8). Let's check if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ commute, so we can determine whether the group is abelian. They don't! So let's check to see if they satisfy the generating for relations for our favorite non-abelian group of order $8$, the dihedral group. Indeed, it is not hard to see
$$\beta \alpha \beta = \alpha^3.$$

It suffices to check this on the two generating elements $(i, \sqrt[5]{5})$. Applying $\alpha^3$ changes $\sqrt[4]{5}$ to $-i\sqrt[4]{5}$, leaving us with $(i, - i\sqrt[4]{5})$. You can check that applying $\beta\alpha\beta$ (in that order!) does the same thing.

So the Galois group is $D_4$ (or $D_8$, depending on your notation). This can also be seen geometrically. The roots of the polynomial form a square in the complex plane (with vertices at $\sqrt[4]{5}, i\sqrt[4]{5}, -\sqrt[4]{5}, -i\sqrt[4]{5}$), and you can see that $\alpha$ rotates them and $\beta$ flips them across the real axis.

Now, using the Galois correspondence, we're looking for the subgroup that fixes $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 5)$. This is the subgroup generated by $\alpha^2$ and $\beta$. I get $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$ for the Galois group over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 5)$, since $\alpha^2$ and $\beta$ commute (check this!).

In retrospect, it seems simpler to just note that $\alpha^2$ and $\beta$ are commuting order 2 automorphisms in your desired (order 4) Galois group, so they generate the entire group.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean about $\beta \alpha \beta = \alpha ^3$ and how you show that $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is generated by $\alpha ^2 $ and $\beta$?

Comment: @Calculus08 I added a few details. First question: I mean those elements are identical as elements of the automorphism group. Second question: You know the group must have order $4$ by the Galois correspondence. You can show that those two distinct elements have order two and commute. So basic group theory shows the group they generate must be $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$. (It can't be the cyclic group of order $4$ because that group only has one element of order $2$.)